# Adding image to LinearLayout each time AlertDialog item is selected

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add an image to a `LinearLayout` each time the user selects an item from an `AlertDialog` modal but once the first item is selected, no other images will appear and the first image doesn't even change to the newly selected item. Ideally, i would like the first image to appear in the center of the layout as it does and when a second choice is selected, I would like it to appear to the right of the first image and then both are centered.

Thanks to anyone looking at this.

Below is the `ImageView` and `LinearLayout` portion of my code.  This code is in the `onClick()` method for the `AlertDialog`

```
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

  LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.picLayout); 
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    imageView.setId(which);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

    int pic = Pic.getPicID(which);
    imageView.setImageResource(pic);


    l.addView(imageView, items.size()-1, params);
```

Comment: set the orientation of your linear layout to horizontal..

Comment: why don't you set the params's width and height to wrap_content, or some number less than width of the parent Linearlayout?

Comment: I set the `LinearLayout` to horizontal and got no change but when I changed the `params` width and height to `WRAP_CONTENT`, I got the second image to also show but not a third and so on.